# Cannot retrieve the id of the last inserted row in Oracle using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I'm using trigger that fires before insert sequence to generate id for a table in Oracle 11g xe

here is my trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER GOOGLEPLAY.ORGANIZATION_CODE_GENERATOR;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GOOGLEPLAY.ORGANIZATION_code_generator
BEFORE INSERT
ON GOOGLEPLAY.ORGANIZATIONS 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

        select ORGANIZATION_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.code from dual;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END ORGANIZATION_code_generator;
```

here is my sequence

```
DROP SEQUENCE GOOGLEPLAY.ORGANIZATION_SEQ;

CREATE SEQUENCE GOOGLEPLAY.ORGANIZATION_SEQ
  START WITH 41
  MAXVALUE 99
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  NOORDER;
```

i want to get this id using hibernate i'm using

```
  session.persist(cashierOrganization);
  session.flush();
  cashierOrganization = (Organizations) session.merge(cashierOrganization);
```

but i always get 0 for the id any suggestions ?

Comment: As a quick side-point: `REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old` is useless, you can remove it. You don't need the `declare` block in the trigger. If you're in 11g `select ORGANIZATION_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.code from dual;` can be rewritten as `:new.code := organization_seq.nextval;` and I suspect a maxvalue of 99 may cause you problems later down the line :-).

Comment: Thanks Ben that was helpful for me thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a custom generator to get the Id set by the trigger during the insert? It's a relative common situation when you work with Oracle. Try to use this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="triggerGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name="triggerGenerator", 
    strategy="package.to.my.custom.generator.TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator")
private Long id;
```

The TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator is a class implementing a custom generator strategy and its implementation is shown in this topic in the Hibernate Forum:

- [Before Insert Trigger and ID generator](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262)

Hope this help!